# Parsing Json Array of Arrays

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, json

This is my first post on stackoverflow so please be patient :-)

I have an Json Array of Arrays:

```
 {
  "response_type": "ok",
  "total_results": 1,
  "page": 1,
  "total_pages": 1,
  "sets": [
    {
      "id": 2075184,
      "created": 1269989599,
      "term_count": 5,
      "has_images": false,
      "terms": [
        [
          "\u9031\u672b",
          "Weekend",
          ""
        ],
        [
          "\u65e5\u66dc\u65e5",
          "Sunday",
          ""
        ],
        [
          "\u571f\u66dc\u65e5",
          "Saturday",
          ""
        ],
        [
          "\u79c1",
          "I, myself",
          ""
        ],
        [
          "\u65e5\u672c\u8a9e",
          "Japanese",
          ""
        ]
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I am using this code in my project to get the "terms" into an NSDictionary:

```
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/json"];

  NSString *jsonreturn = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];  
  NSData *jsonData = [jsonreturn dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding];
  NSError *error = nil;
  NSDictionary * dict = [[CJSONDeserializer deserializer] deserializeAsDictionary:jsonData error:&error];

  NSLog(@"dict1: %@", dict);
  if (dict)
  {
    rows = [dict objectForKey:@"sets"];
  }

  NSLog(@"Array: %@", rows);
```

However I am having trouble figuring out how to get the terms separated for example:

```
[
          "\u9031\u672b",
          "Weekend",
          ""
        ],
```

I would like an NSArray of all the Japanese: "\u9031\u672b"(that is japanese btw) and an NSArray of all the definitions Weekend (Or a NSDictionary). However I am not sure how to separate them.  We can safely assume that all the Japanese is 0 and all the definitions are 1.  Any help would be wonderful!

thank you,

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using the [JSON Framework](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/) for Objective-C iPhone?

Comment: I have, can it handle this better?  Any tutorials or examples would be wonderful.

Comment: @leachianus - `NSDictionary * dict = [jsonreturn JSONValue];` There's your tutorial.

Comment: @leachianus a method provided by the JSON framework.  It's how you do all the json parsing.

Comment: Ah, so I see how much easier that is: 

 NSString *jsonreturn = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url]; 
 NSDictionary * dict = [jsonreturn JSONValue];
 
 NSLog(@"%@", dict);

However I have arrived at the same problem,  How do I take the terms and separate them?

thank you,

Comment: did you figure it out? the NSDictionary can contain NSDictionaries inside it, so for your example, you'd have a String value of "ok" in the dictionary with the key "response_type" and also a dictionary called "set" in the dictionary. which would be a nested NSDictionary. Looking at a plist file may help you better understand if that's confusing.

Comment: NSJSONSerialization has been around since two OSs now, use it instead!

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>     [
>     "\u9031\u672b",
>     "Weekend",
>     ""
>     ],
> ```
>
> I would like an NSArray of all the Japanese: "\u9031\u672b"(that is japanese btw) and an NSArray of all the definitions Weekend (Or a NSDictionary). However I am not sure how to separate them. We can safely assume that all the Japanese is 0 and all the definitions are 1.

So element 0 (and likewise element 1) may be a string or an array, and if it's not an array, you want to wrap it in an array?

Just do that, then. [Get element](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/objectAtIndex:) 0, [test whether it's an](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/isKindOfClass:) array, and [wrap it in one](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSArray/arrayWithObject:) if it isn't. Then, do the same for element 1.

You might consider making some changes on the server side, if you can: Serve up the data as a dictionary with keys chosen for clarity, rather than an array with magic indexes, and have any values that are zero-or-more or one-or-more always be arrays.